# Change Password In Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I've add code to change password in my webapp. But `Hash::check()`    doesn't work. Always return false. Also `Hash::Make()` returns    different string every time. I've tried `bcrypt()` instead but, it also    doesn't work. Please help me. Here's my code.

```
public function changePassword(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $curPassword = $request->input['curPassword'];
    $newPassword = $request->input['newPassword'];

    if (Hash::check($curPassword, $user->password)) {
        $user_id = $user->id;
        $obj_user = User::find($user_id)->first();
        $obj_user->password = Hash::make($newPassword);
        $obj_user->save();

        return response()->json(["result"=>true]);
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json(["result"=>false]);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: it should be `$request->input('curPassword');` not `$request->input['curPassword'];`

Comment: Check https://www.5balloons.info/setting-up-change-password-with-laravel-authentication/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your $curPassword variable is empty, that's why it's always returning false. Try this way

```
$curPassword = $request->curPassword;
$newPassword = $request->newPassword;
```

Unless you send data in an `input` array. But somewhoe, `Hash::check()` is failing, meaning there is no match.

As for the same string, yes, `Hash::make()` always returns a different string. I guess for security purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried as you said. But also it doesn't work.

Comment: Finally, I've fixed. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Heres how I did it:

In my controller, I use the following method:

```
public function changePassword()
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'current_password' => 'required|current_password',
        'new_password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);

    request()->user()->fill([
        'password' => Hash::make(request()->input('new_password'))
    ])->save();
    request()->session()->flash('success', 'Password changed!');

    return redirect()->route('password.change');
}
```

This will validate the input, then properly save the new password for the current user. It also flashes a message and then returns them to the password change form. You can remove that part and do your own thing there.

This utilizes a custom validation rule I created called `current_password`. You must add this to your `AppServiceProvider::boot()` method like so:

```
public function boot()
{
    // current password validation rule
    Validator::extend('current_password', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        return Hash::check($value, Auth::user()->password);
    });
}
```

Just make sure you're using the `Auth`, `Hash`, and `Validator` facades in the `AppServiceProvider`.

Lastly, we simply need to declare our error message in our `lang/en/validation.php` file:

```
'current_password' => "The :attribute is invalid.",
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
 $curPassword =$request->input('curPassword');
 $newPassword = $request->input('newPassword');
```

not

```
 $curPassword = $request->input['curPassword'];
 $newPassword = $request->input['newPassword'];
```

In Laravel [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing#basic-usage) they are saying if you want to change the password what you could do after the checking is

```
 $request->user()->fill([
            'password' => Hash::make($request->newPassword)
        ])->save();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried as you said. But also it doesn't work.

Comment: try `dd($request)` your data and see what you'll get.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It was my mistake. I was sending wrong value when post request.

Answer (score 0):

There is also error in this line

```
$obj_user = User::find($user_id)->first();
```

it should be

```
$obj_user = User::find($user_id);
```

As official documentation say

```
// Retrieve a model by its primary key...
$flight = App\Flight::find(1);

// Retrieve the first model matching the query constraints...
$flight = App\Flight::where('active', 1)->first();
```